# VBA Help to Copy Worksheet from Excel into Word

Tags: excel, vba, function, ms-word

I am creating a service contract for a client.  The document has an Appendix that is a table that changes depending on the product.  All of the Appendix tables are in Excel, and I have created an INDEX MATCH function to return the name of a Named Range according to the product chosen, and now I need Excel to actually display that range.

This is my function:

```
=INDEX(References,MATCH(A2,Reference!A2:A30,0),MATCH(B2,Reference!B1:D1,0))
```

It returns a Named Range because that's the data I have in the table:
["References"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln4EH.png), but I want it to display the table and not just its name.

My ultimate goal is to have Word display the correct table depending on choices selected in form fields within the contract.  Basically, I want to automate copying the correct table from Excel into Word.  It needs to keep its original formatting.  Pasting as an object or image is acceptable.

Comment: Am not too familiar with using VBA in Microsoft Word, but based on this link https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba, the actual copying of the table from Excel to Word is like two lines. `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").ListObjects("TableName").Range.Copy`, then `Word.Application.Documents("DocumentName").Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False`. That won't work as is, you'll need to create and set an object reference to `Word.Application` (if the code is in Excel).

Comment: But the rest of the syntax should be as shown.

Comment: @chillin Thank you!  What would the language be to draw "SheetName" from the INDEX MATCH formula?  Is that even possible?

Comment: You should be able to get the result of the Index Match formula: `Dim refSheet as worksheet: Set refSheet = Thisworkbook.worksheets("References")`, then try assigning the formula's result to some variable like `result = application.Index(refSheet.range("References"),application.MATCH(A2,refSheet.range("A2:A30"),0),application.MATCH(B2,refSheet.range("B1:D1"),0))`. The thing is you'll need to replace the `B2` and `A2` with either a value or a range (I don't know what sheet `A2` or `B2` are on but something like `thisworkbook.worksheets("whateversheet").range("A2")`). Hope that's clear.